# Unable to create mock object where the actual object is being created using new in the main code

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have a class definition like below,

```
@Component
@EnableKafka
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "load", name = "kafka.config", havingValue = "True")
public class InsightApiKafkaScheduler extends InsightsAPISchedulerService {

    @Value("${kafka.source.topic}")
    String sourceTopic;

    private final ConsumerFactory<String,String> consumerFactory;
    List<String> insightsMessages;

    private final CompanyDeviceService deviceServiceImpl;
    private final CompanyDeviceService companyServiceImpl;
    private final WaterMarkUpdationServiceImpl waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl;
    private final RestService restService;
    private final KafkaService kafkaService;

    @Autowired
    public InsightApiKafkaScheduler(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory, CompanyDeviceService deviceServiceImpl, CompanyDeviceService companyServiceImpl, WaterMarkUpdationServiceImpl waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl, RestService restService, KafkaService kafkaService) {
        this.consumerFactory = consumerFactory;
        this.deviceServiceImpl = deviceServiceImpl;
        this.companyServiceImpl = companyServiceImpl;
        this.restService = restService;
        this.kafkaService = kafkaService;
        this.auditPayload = new ArrayList<>();
        this.waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl = waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl;
    }

    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "${insights.api.schedule}")
    public void consumeMessages(){
        insightsMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        log.debug(String.valueOf(consumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties()));
        KafkaConsumer<String,String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties());
        ...
        ConsumerRecords<String,String> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(20000L));
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Now when I am trying to write a test case for `consumeMessages()`, I'll need to create a mock object of `KafkaConsumer` in order to further mock the `consumerRecords` data returned by `kafkaConsumer.poll()`. Since `KafkaConsumer` object is being created here using `new`, I tried using below to get a mock,

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = Mockito.mock(KafkaConsumer.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaConsumer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(kafkaConsumer);
```

However, it does not work and the program goes on to create a real object of `KafkaConsumer` while control goes in the actual code.

Provided I'll not be able to make any changes/refactoring in the actual code, how can I create a mock object of `KafkaConsumer` here?

Edit: Here is how I am trying to write the test case,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class InsightApiKafkaSchedulerTest {

    
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Mock
    private ConsumerFactory<String,String> consumerFactory;

    @Mock
    private WaterMarkUpdationServiceImpl waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

    @Mock
    private CompanyServiceImpl companyServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private DeviceServiceImpl deviceServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private RestService restService;

    @Mock
    private KafkaService kafkaService;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private InsightApiKafkaScheduler insightApiKafkaScheduler;
    
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(insightApiKafkaScheduler, "deviceServiceImpl", deviceServiceImpl);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(insightApiKafkaScheduler, "companyServiceImpl", companyServiceImpl);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(insightApiKafkaScheduler,"waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl", waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(insightApiKafkaScheduler,"consumerFactory",consumerFactory);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(insightApiKafkaScheduler,"restService", restService);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(insightApiKafkaScheduler,"kafkaService", kafkaService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConsumeMessages() throws Exception {
        long startOffset = 10L;
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = buildConsumerRecords();

        HashMap<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"my-server.com:9092");
        
        when(consumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties()).thenReturn(config);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaConsumer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(kafkaConsumer);
        TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("my-source-topic", 0);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(TopicPartition.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(topicPartition);
        
        when(kafkaConsumer.poll(any(Duration.class))).thenReturn(consumerRecords);
        when(waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl.getWatermark()).thenReturn(startOffset);
        doNothing().when(companyServiceImpl).sendMessages(any(), any());
        doNothing().when(kafkaService).commitOffsetsToKafka(any(), any(), any());
        doNothing().when(waterMarkUpdationServiceImpl).updateProcessTracking(any());

        insightApiKafkaScheduler.consumeMessages();
    }

    private ConsumerRecords<String, String> buildConsumerRecords() {
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // populates messages with test data
        
        return records;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share how you your test looks like - it is not so clear how you inject the mock from your question....

Comment: Sure, updated above.